# Adding custom properties in workflow task at "workflow I have started " page alfresco share

Tags: share, alfresco, alfresco-webscripts, alfresco-enterprise

I need to add custom properties in task row at the "workflow I have started" page.By default one task bar/row contains properties such as due,description,type and started.How to customize to add our custom properties along/instead of these properties.

Answer (score 2):

You can define new form in form configuration with id as **workflow-details**.Check share-workflow-form-config.xml for more details.Given below is the example of one form taken from the same file, which is defining properties of the page you mentioned.

```
<config evaluator="task-type" condition="bpm:startTask">
  <forms>
     <form id="workflow-details">
        <field-visibility>
           <show id="bpm:sendEMailNotifications" />
           <show id="packageItems" />
        </field-visibility>
        <appearance>
           <set id="" appearance="title" label-id="workflow.set.workflow.more_info" />
           <set id="items" appearance="title" label-id="workflow.set.items" />

           <field id="packageItems" set="items" />
        </appearance>
     </form>

     <form>
        <field-visibility>
           <show id="message" />
           <show id="taskOwner" />
           <show id="bpm:workflowPriority" />
           <show id="bpm:workflowDueDate" />
           <show id="bpm:taskId" />
           <show id="bpm:status" />
           <show id="packageItems" />
           <show id="bpm:sendEMailNotifications" />
        </field-visibility>
        <appearance>
           <set id="" appearance="title" label-id="workflow.set.task.info" />
           <set id="info" appearance="" template="/org/alfresco/components/form/3-column-set.ftl" />
           <set id="progress" appearance="title" label-id="workflow.set.task.progress" />
           <set id="items" appearance="title" label-id="workflow.set.items" />
           <set id="other" appearance="title" label-id="workflow.set.other" />

           <field id="message">
              <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/info.ftl" />
           </field>
           <field id="taskOwner" set="info" />
           <field id="bpm:taskId" set="info">
              <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/info.ftl" />
           </field>
           <field id="bpm:workflowPriority" label-id="workflow.field.priority" set="info" read-only="true">
              <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/workflow/priority.ftl" />
           </field>
           <field id="bpm:workflowDueDate" set="info" label-id="workflow.field.due">
              <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/info.ftl" />
           </field>
           <field id="bpm:status" set="progress" />
           <field id="bpm:sendEMailNotifications" set="other" />
           <field id="packageItems" set="items" />
        </appearance>
     </form>
  </forms>
```